# How can I install a previous version of Python 3 in macOS using homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

How can I install a previous version of Python 3 in macOS using brew?

With the command `brew install python` I got the latest version of Python 3 (currently v3.7.0), but I want the last version of Python 3.6 (currently 3.6.5).

I have read about another package `pyenv` that can assist in handle different python installation, but this solution is not suitable for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, Homebrew's support for multiple versions of Python is abysmal, and is progressively getting worse. I would recommend you avoid using Homebrew to install Python at all. Python.org provides [macOS install packages for various versions of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) which can be installed side-by-side with each other (and side-by-side with a Homebrew Python installation if you want). Either using those packages or using a tool like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) will ultimately save you a lot of grief in the long run.

Comment: @DanielPryden imo pyenv should be recommended before going to the website to manually download and install. People that already use homebrew are probably searching for a nice commandline solution. For anyone scrolling through here, scroll down: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189988/4600952

Answer (score 268, accepted):

### Short Answer

To make a clean install of Python 3.6.5 use:

```
brew unlink python # ONLY if you have installed (with brew) another version of python 3
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

If you prefer to recover a previously installed version, then:

```
brew info python           # To see what you have previously installed
brew switch python 3.x.x_x # Ex. 3.6.5_1
```

### Long Answer

There are two formulas for installing Python with Homebrew: `python@2` and `python`.
The first is for Python 2 and the second for Python 3.

**Note:** You can find outdated answers on the web where it is mentioned `python3` as the formula name for installing Python version 3. Now it's just `python`!

By default, with these formulas you can install the latest version of the corresponding major version of Python. So, you cannot directly install a minor version like 3.6.

#### Solution

With `brew`, you can install a package using the address of the formula, for example in a git repository.

```
brew install https://the/address/to/the/formula/FORMULA_NAME.rb
```

Or specifically for Python 3

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/COMMIT_IDENTIFIER/Formula/python.rb
```

The address you must specify is the address to the last commit of the formula (python.rb) for the desired version.
You can find the commint identifier by looking at the history for homebrew-core/Formula/python.rb

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/python.rb

### Python > 3.6.5

In the link above you will not find a formula for a version of Python above 3.6.5.
After the maintainers of that (official) repository released Python 3.7, they only submit updates to the recipe of Python 3.7.

As explained above, with homebrew you have only Python 2 (python@2) and Python 3 (python), **there is no explicit formula for Python 3.6**.

Although those minor updates are mostly irrelevant in most cases and for most users, I will search if someone has done an explicit formula for 3.6.

Comment: How will this affect or interact with packages in Homebrew that rely on the default python3 interpreter?

Comment: I do not use (or even know) about any package *distributed with Homebrew* that relies on Python3 (maybe there are, I just don't use any).
Brew will install Pip together with Python, so after that, I use pip to install all Python packages.

Comment: In any case, a Python depending applications (installed with brew or not) will look for a python3 executable in the applications path, and you will have python3 pointing to python3.6.
Thus, your default Python 3 will be 3.6 (if you use the example above) and that should be enough.
Python 3.7 is so recent; I doubt there is an application that requires explicitly Python 3.7, in the same way, I don't know any application that only works with Python 3.6.
In other words. You will be fine :)

Comment: I have 3.7 installed and received this error: `Error: python 3.7.0 is already installed
To install 3.6.5_1, first run `brew unlink python`` when using the 'short answer'.

Comment: Thank you for providing the direct commit link for 3.6.5. You saved me from a hopeless situation.

Comment: I know this is a bit older, but I am struggling trying to figure out how you got the link to the formula. The current version of 3.6 is 3.6.7, is there some simple approach to finding this formula?

Comment: Hola @diek. Unfortunately in the official repository there is no formula for python > 3.6.5. I just edit my answer to explain this. I will also look for a solution.

Comment: How do you uninstall the python3.6.5 version if you don't need it anymore?

Comment: This does't work for me on OS X 10.14.4/XCode 10.2.1 (10E1001). python fails to build, brew sphinx-build is missing. Not sure everyone will want to run it with `--ignore-dependencies`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you and thank you. The direct link for 3.6.5 has been very valuable to many developers!

Comment: @ePi272314 Thanks. Have a question. How come I can't find this commit identifier: f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558 inside the history for homebrew-core/Formula/python.rb?

Comment: Hello @Jun711. Go first to <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core> and then search for `f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558`; make sure you select `in this repository`. Click `Commits` on the left on the results page.

Comment: @ePi272314 thanks. I can see it through git log now too. I thought it was done searching but it took some time to search for the commit hash.

Comment: What happens when I `brew upgrade` after this? Will that upgrade Python to not-3.6? Can I prevent that somehow?

Comment: Answer to @Johan Walles. I cannot remember of any problem with this method and `brew upgrade`. Theoretically, you should be fine. The upgrade command should only upgrade installed formulae, and because you are not using the formula `python`, you should not get any upgrade of that formula. In fact, the disadvantage of this method is that you will be frozen in Python 3.6.5 (while the current version in 3.6.9)

Comment: After following this, when attempting to pip install for this installed version, I get SSL errors from PIP.

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin/pip3 install pylint`
> `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
`

Comment: @Patrick that `.../pip3` is an alias or a binary? If it is an alias, check it is pointing to the right place.

Comment: It was the correct one from 3.6. I abandoned this approach completely and switched to Pyenv + pyenv-virtualenv. thanks!

Comment: On Catalina I get `Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported`

Comment: Hello @m.spyratos. Try installing from a different repository. Ex. `brew install sashkab/python/python@3.x` where x ∊ {6,7,8}

Answer (score 44):

I have tried everything but could not make it work. Finally I have used `pyenv` and it worked directly like a charm.

So having `homebrew` installed, juste do:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.6.5
```

to manage virtualenvs:

```
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.5 env_name
```

See [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) for more info.

#### EDIT (2020/03/19)

I have found using the [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) easier than homebrew to install pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv direclty:

```sh
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

To manage python version, either globally:

```
pyenv global 3.6.5
```

or locally in a given directory:

```
pyenv local 3.6.5
```

Comment: This is actually not directly answering the question but instead circumventing it by a `virtualenv` approach.

Comment: actually the virtualenv is not necessary. `pyenv` lets you manage python versions without the need of using a venv

Comment: I guess this is the nicest solution in most circumstances

Comment: After mac 12.3 upgrade, it is failing for - "The Python zlib extension was not compiled"

Answer (score 32):

As an update, when doing

```sh
brew unlink python # If you have installed (with brew) another version of python
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

You may encounter

```
Error: python contains a recursive dependency on itself:
  python depends on sphinx-doc
  sphinx-doc depends on python
```

To bypass it, add the `--ignore-dependencies` argument to brew install.

```sh
brew unlink python # If you have installed (with brew) another version of python
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

Comment: and then you'll have a nightmare with dependency hell... like https://discourse.brew.sh/t/brew-install-python3-fails/1756/7

Comment: this didn't work for me at first; essentially had to do this:

brew install --debug --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb

and once it fails in make html, just ignore the error by selecting 2). the html/docs failure will probably bite me later on, but for now it's working fine :shrug:

Answer (score 29):

What I did was first I installed python 3.7 and then unlinked it using the following commands

```
brew install python3
brew unlink python
```

then I installed python 3.6.5 using the following command taken from above answer.

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb --ignore-dependencies
```

After that I ran the following command

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

Now I have all pythons in the system. To find out run

```
mian@tdowrick2~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.10
mian@tdowrick2~ $ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.1
mian@tdowrick2~ $ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

To create Python 3.7 virtual environment.

```
mian@tdowrick2~ $ virtualenv -p python3.7 env
Already using interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/mian/env/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/mian/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
mian@tdowrick2~ $ source env/bin/activate
(env) mian@tdowrick2~ $ python --version
Python 3.7.1
(env) mian@tdowrick2~ $ deactivate
```

To create Python 3.6 virtual environment

```
mian@tdowrick2~ $ virtualenv -p python3.6 env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/mian/env/bin/python3.6
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/mian/env/bin/python (you must use /Users/mian/env/bin/python3.6)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
mian@tdowrick2~ $ source env/bin/activate
(env) mian@tdowrick2~ $ python --version
Python 3.6.5
(env) mian@tdowrick2~ $ deactivate
```

Comment: While this looks like it would be great, it no longer works, the result is:
`python -V && python3.7 -V && python3 -V && python3.6 -V`

`Python 2.7.15
Python 3.7.3
Python 3.7.3
zsh: command not found: python3.6`

Comment: Look closely my answer, for 3.6 you have to write python3.6 -V.
You have done `python3 -V` twice thats why you are getting `3.7.3` twice and missing `3.6`

Comment: For me, this hides `python3.6` under `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/bin`.  Once I made a link, it works as you say.  This python self management system seems to be a rube goldberg fractal of a million programmers coding by brownian motion.

Answer (score 15):

I tried all the answers above to install Python 3.4.4. The installation of python worked, but PIP would not be installed and nothing I could do to make it work. I was using Mac OSX Mojave, which cause some issues with zlib, openssl.

**What not to do:**

- Try to avoid using Homebrew for previous version given by the formula **Python** or **Python3**.
- Do not try to compile *Python*

**Solution:**

1. Download the **macOS 64-bit installer** or **macOS 64-bit/32-bit installer**: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/
2. In previous step, it will download *Python 3.6.5*, if for example, you want to download *Python 3.4.4*, replace in the url above **python-365** by **python-344**
3. Download click on the file you downloaded a GUI installer will open
4. If you downloaded *python-365*, after installation, to launch this version of python, you will type in your terminal *python365*, same thing for pip, it will be *pip365*

p.s: You don't have to uninstall your other version of Python on your system.

---

**Edit:**

---

I found a much much much better solution that work on MacOSX, Windows, Linux, etc.

1. It doesn't matter if you have already python installed or not.
2. Download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)
3. Once installed, in terminal type: `conda init`
4. In terminal,create virtual environment with *any* python version, for example, I picked 3.4.4: `conda create -n [NameOfYour VirtualEnvironment] python=3.4.4`
5. Then, in terminal, you can check all the virtual environment you ahave created with the command: `conda info --envs`
6. Then, in terminal, activate the virtual environment of your choice with: `conda activate [The name of your virtual environment that was shown with the command at step 5]`

Comment: This worked for me.. on mac catalina.. I had 3.9 & 3.7.. installed 3.6.5 by first method.. only difference now is to launch this version of python, you will type in your terminal python3.6, same thing for pip, it will be pip3.6

Also you can check the installation by :- python3.6 --version

Comment: For anyone looking at 2021-12-07, conda way is the best and only way that worked for me personally.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone face pip issue like below

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

The root cause is openssl 1.1 doesn’t support python 3.6 anymore. So you need to install old version openssl 1.0

here is the solution:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with `homebrew`, you can temporarily backdate `homebrew-core` and set the `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE` variable to hold it in place:

```
cd `brew --repo homebrew/core`
git checkout f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
brew install python
```

I don't recommend permanently backdating homebrew-core, as you will miss out on security patches, but it is useful for testing purposes.

You can also extract old versions of homebrew formulae into your own tap (tap_owner/tap_name) using the `brew extract` command:

```
brew extract python tap_owner/tap_name --version=3.6.5
```

Comment: How do I figure out the tap_owner and tap_name for a given package?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me was to install Anaconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

There I can create as many environments with different Python versions as I want and switch between them with a mouse click. It could not be easier.

To install different Python versions just follow these instructions https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

A new development environment with a different Python version was done within 2 minutes. And in the future I can easily switch back and forth.