# Installing Python3.6 alongside Python3.7 on Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, python-3.6, python-3.7

I'm trying to install tensorflow onto a Mac with Python3.7. However, I'm getting the error:

```
$ pip3 -v install tensorflow
...    
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/7a/c6bca0fe52a94ca508731d8b139e7dbd5a36cddc64c19f422f97e5a853e8/tensorflow-1.10.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=3ab24374888d6a13d55ce2e3cf4ba0c9cd6f824723313db5322512087525cb78 (from https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/); it is not compatible with this Python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/private/var/folders/4n/9342s4wd3jv0qzwjz8rxrygr0000gp/T/pip-req-tracker-3p60r2lo'

No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

From what I can gather this is happening because tensorflow doesn't yet support Python3.7. As a workaround I want to install Python3.6 alongside 3.7 and then install tensorflow to that version. However, I'm new to Mac and not sure of the correct way to do this without potentially messing with the preexisting Python version.

I've tried using brew, but it looks like Python3 is as specific as it gets. What is the correct way to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Try using `brew` for example if already using Python 3:

```
$ brew unlink python
```

Then [install python 3.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125014/1135424):

```
$ brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

To get back to python `3.7.4_1` use:

```
$ brew switch python 3.7.4_1
```

And if need 3.6 again switch with:

```
$ brew switch python 3.6.5_1
```

Comment: I get the error `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python`

Comment: I added --ignore-dependecies to make it work (recursive dependency error with sphinx-doc):
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb

Comment: Is available a brew Formula link for Python 3.6.7? Python 3.6.5 has some severe issues - https://bugs.python.org/issue24658 and its install should be avoided!

Comment: I had this problem as well `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python` . It solved by installing python, the latest version, using brew, then unlink it and so on. So first install the latest version using brew.

Comment: For some reason switching between python versions doesn't work for me. Instead, whereever I would use `python`, I use `python3.6` instead, and when installing packages with pip, I use `python3.6 -m pip install package_name`

Comment: For some reason, my network using python3.6 wasn't work on macOS Catalina with zsh, so I ran: `$ brew doctor && brew missing` it shows me that openssl lib for some reason not installed and then install it using: `$ brew install openssl`.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see which versions are installed? (i.e. which options can be switched to)

Comment: `Error: Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract python` to a stable tap on GitHub instead.` Please update the answer to fit this

Answer (score 50):

If you are using mac, you can install pyenv from Brew, install the desired versions, list the installed versions, and activate each version locally or globally.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.6.9
pyenv install 3.7.4    
pyenv versions
pyenv global 3.7.4 3.6.9
```

```
$ python3.6 --version 
Python 3.6.9 

$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.4
```

PS: Global activation worked only after restarting the computer. You need to prepend `$(pyenv root)/shims` to the *left* of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I haven't used `pyenv` before. What do I do after the last command? `python36 myscript.py` and `python3.7 myscript.py` both fail.

Comment: Add, the answer is to prepend `$(pyenv root)/shims` to the `PATH`. I'll update the answer to say so.

Comment: doing what @SaravanakumarG is suggesting completely broke my terminal, I couldn't use a single command anymore. The right way is `export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"`

Comment: If you mistakenly messed up your PATH by following what @SaravanakumarG is suggesting, just run PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
 in your terminal, fix the export statement and then source the file again 

source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Having issues with `pyenv install 3.6.9` on M1 mac

Comment: correct path set up : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv

Comment: *NOTE* As of November, 2023 — you NEED this way, as `brew install` does not support direct install of python version 3.6 anymore. So, stick this way for any special old versions.

Answer (score 12):

When you mess around with system python versions, I strongly recommend using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) - it makes life so much easier. You would simply run

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.6.5
pyenv install 3.7.4
```

Then you can run `pyenv local [python version]`

Comment: This doesn't seem to override system installed python version