# Mac install python3.6 with brew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I want to install python version 3.6.
when I do `brew install python` it installs latest version of python i.e `3.8`.

I tried below solution but it is giving me error.

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

Error:

> Error: Calling Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python' to stable tap on GitHub instead.

I even tried solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125013/how-can-i-install-a-previous-version-of-python-3-in-macos-using-homebrew) but not working.

Also When I do:

```
brew search python
```

I don't find `python@3.6` init

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726203/installing-python3-6-alongside-python3-7-on-mac

Answer (score 38):

Maybe you should do `pyenv` to manage the different python versions.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.6.5
pyenv install 3.7.4
```

If you want to control the shell to use different python versions, you can try this:

```
pyenv shell 3.6.5
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this step fails for me with the following error.                        
                                                                                                                                        
 BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5q/x_5xtv2x6kn8qwdwmgll08nh0000gp/T/python-build.20210715111610.57131
....