# Python 3.6.5_1 installed in incorrect location (Mac OS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv

I install python 3.6.5_1 using

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.r
```

and get

> Warning: python 3.6.5_1 is already installed
>
> The currently linked version is 3.7.3
>
> You can use `brew switch python 3.6.5_1` to link this version.

I use  `brew switch python 3.6.5_1` and get

> Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1
>
> Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3
>
> 4 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1

Typing `which python3`, there is no output, `which python` gives

> /usr/local/bin/python

and typing `python3` gives

-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
typing `python` gives

> Python 2.7.15 (default, Nov 27 2018, 21:24:58) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

How do I make sure that the installed python3.6.5_1 is installed at correct location and is the one referred to by `python3`?

**Extra background** :

I have been working with OpenCV for around 5 months now, [following this installation guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/) for installing all requirements including python3.6. I was using this version of brew's python instead of mac's one. Recently I had to install FFmpeg, some errors came up, unwittingly I did something (I don't remember, probably unlinked python) and then I wasn't able to install FFmpeg anyway but also this destroyed my workspace. Right now I keep getting the following error everytime I open up terminal:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
>   virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
>
> If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>   check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
>   set properly.

I tried `brew install python3` and that solves the above warning for virtualenvwrapper. But it installs python3.7.3, whereas I need python3.6 for tensor flow etc.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python. Is it possible that Python 3 is the default and just referenced as python? Can you type the banner from when you run `python`? Is it possible that you have a path issue and the system Python is being invoked?

Comment: What it shows when you pass `python` in the terminal? Please add that to your post to get a better understanding.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah Kindly check my edit, the problem is definitely that python3.6 is not getting installed at the correct location. May be I should do a clean uninstall of everything?

Comment: Try installing python from python.org. I'm a Mac user too and so far I haven't faced any problems by installing python like this. Hope it helps. Link:-  https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

Comment: Try Using Conda for all the installations for python. Get it here: https://www.anaconda.com/

Comment: Personally, I'd stick with Homebrew. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125013/how-can-i-install-a-previous-version-of-python-3-in-macos-using-homebrew. This should allow you to install python 3.6.5.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah I deleted everything from usr/local and did fresh install as in above link(which I was doing anyway, but didn't work) and I think the problem is solved. Let's see till I try to install FFmpeg again.

Comment: Make sure to look at the requirements for FFmpeg before you install it, and make sure that if there is anything to build that it is referencing your Python 3.6.5 installation.