# brew how to install python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I have a mac and want to install python 3.6
I tried:

```
$brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

But got:

```
Error: Calling Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python' to stable tap on GitHub instead.
```

So I tried:

```
$brew extract python https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

But got:

```
Error: Invalid tap name 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb'
```

What should I do?

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125013/how-can-i-install-a-previous-version-of-python-3-in-macos-using-homebrew/51125014#51125014)

Comment: @marcdecline I did , and I received the error written aboce

Comment: Did you try what the error tells you to do?

Comment: @bfontaine Yes of course but didn't work (edited the original post)

Comment: Can you download the `.rb` file then run `brew install ./python.rb`?

Comment: @bfontaine I get the error: Error: python: Calling 'devel' blocks in formulae is disabled! Use 'head' blocks or @-versioned formulae instead.

Comment: …ok, so if you remove the line from `devel do` to the `end` 3 lines below and try again, does it work?

Comment: @bfontaine what do you mean? in the python.rb I have the lines:

  devel do
    url "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0rc1.tar.xz"
    sha256 "c9cfb9b60c23e3ed20e942fdeee299b27c0b4abd7def9b4a3a78d37e6c0c0bb7"
  end

What should I put instead?

Comment: Remove it altogether