# Mac OS 11.4 Big Sur - fixing python cryptography package in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, python-cryptography

I bought a MacBook Pro 13 M1 (16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD) and I'm trying to get it setup for work and part of that is using python 2 (yes I know it's end of life, I still need to use it till we finish porting to go).  I have some python packages I'd like to remove from my system python2 (I'm sure I must've run sudo pip install on these at some point, which I know was stupid, but what is done is done) and now that I'm on Big Sur I can't remove these packages.  I tried disabling SIP until I can get them removed (`csrutil disable` from recovery), but now I'm getting errors that I can't remove files from a read only filesystem

```
sudo pip uninstall cryptography                                                                                                                                                                                            2  14:34
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/darren/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Found existing installation: cryptography 3.3.2
Uninstalling cryptography-3.3.2:
  Would remove:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography-3.3.2-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 90, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 686, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 403, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 292, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 355, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 323, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 270, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 275, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 273, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/_der.py'
```

but I can't remount root as read/write and get this error when I try:

```
sudo mount -uw /
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66
```

How do I remove these files from /System/Library if it's read only?  Do I have to format my system and start from scratch now that mac os put these files in a read only filesystem or is there a way to remove them?

**Edit:**

So I have broken packages in /System/Library that are preventing fabric from running so I can't get our stuff up and running.  The main one being the cryptography package.  So I either need to fix these packages so fabric can run or remove them or something.

The other part that makes this such a pain is that I'm trying to run python 2 on an M1 Mac which means either using the built in python or using rosetta with an x86 python2 as I have found no method for installing arm python 2 on an M1 Mac (there isn't an installer from python.org or brew since python2 was end of life when the M1 Macs shipped).

**Edit2:**

Maybe these packages that I'm having issues with did ship with Mac OS as the package's folder's created timestamp is "Jan 1 01:00:00 2020" just like every other file & folder in that same folder.  If so I guess I need to fix them somehow.  When I try to run fab from the command line I get this error in the cryptography package:

```
fab
/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
    from fabric.main import program
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/fabric/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import Config, Connection
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 16, in <module>
    from paramiko.agent import AgentRequestHandler
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 129, in <module>
    class Transport(threading.Thread, ClosingContextManager):
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 190, in Transport
    if KexCurve25519.is_available():
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 30, in is_available
    X25519PrivateKey.generate()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py", line 39, in generate
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 117, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _DTLS_client_method
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 120, in _join_lingering_threads
    for thr in _active_threads:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Users/darren/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 120, in _join_lingering_threads
    for thr in _active_threads:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Has anyone else had this problem or have a fix for it?

Comment: You can't, and aren't expected to, and shouldn't. _Don't_ delete these files at all; if you don't want to use this Python installation, just stop using it. Note that this Python installation **is part of MacOS Itself**, so if you reinstall MacOS, it'll still be there. You cannot have a valid installation of Big Sur without these files.

Comment: Note that `sudo pip install` can't change these files any more than `rm` can.

Comment: **Don't** mess with the built-in installation as it is used by some OS components. If you must use Python 2.7, use virtual environments for each project to manage dependencies on a per-project basis (which is the best practice anyway).

Comment: @DeepSpace That's all well and good and I'll do that going forward, but that doesn't get me out of the situation I'm in where there are broken packages in the built in python and so now I can't run fabric or other things in python until they're fixed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, so then why did Mac OS ship with broken packages and how do I fix them?  I'd love to use a different python and when I last used Mac OS (about 4 - 6 years ago) I used a brew installed python2, but that's not an option on an M1 Mac and the only option appears to be the built in python for python2 on an M1 mac without using rosetta2, which may be what I end up having to do.  Either that or run it in a Linux VM in which case I might as well sell this Mac and buy a laptop to install Linux on natively.

Comment: @nobled, you don't need to fix them. Just _don't use them at all_. It doesn't matter if there's a broken package somewhere on the system if you're using a completely different Python interpreter that doesn't ever try to import it, or if you have a virtualenv created without the option to enable system packages (back in the day that option was on-by-default and had to be turned off, but in modern times it's off-by-default).

Comment: @nobled, ...also, you can totally install a different Python interpreter on a M1. `brew` might not do it, but Nix totally will. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653464/installation-of-earlier-versions-of-python-prior-to-3-8-fails-on-mac-with-m1-c

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your recommendation.  I haven't used or heard of nix before, but I was able to install python2 via nix and then install pip and then cryptography and now fabric is working!

Comment: BTW, you can tell Nix to install Python modules (like pip, or cryptography) for you. `python27.withPackages (p: [p.pip p.cryptography])`, for example. `nix-build -E '((import <nixpkgs> {}).python27.withPackages (p: [p.pip p.cryptography]))'` is one way one might actually run that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to install python2 for Apple Silicon/M1 from nix and then I had to manually install pip which let me install cryptography & cffi (I had libffi installed from brew).  Here are the steps I used, I'm not sure if they're all necessary, but it's what I did:

- Install Nix

  - see https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation for more details, but if you have a mac with a T2 chip or M1 this will still be encrypted
  - `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume --daemon`
- Install python2 from nix

  - `nix-env -i python-2.7.18`
  - verify that you're using this python in a new terminal session (you'll need to start a new shell to get the updated path)

    - run `which python`
    - if it doesn't return something like `/Users/user/.nix-profile/bin/python` you'll want to add `~/.nix-profile/bin` to the front of your path, start a new shell, and run `which python` again
- Install pip

  - See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py for more details, but if you curl the `get-pip.py` in this url and run it with python 2 it'll tell you to instead download and use the `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
  - `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
  - `python ./get-pip.py`
- Use brew to install `libiff` and `openssl@1.1`

  - I had done this step previously and I'm not 100% sure it's necessary, but I believe it is
  - `brew install libiff openssl@1.1`
  - Add the following to your .bashrc, .zshrc, .profile, or wherever you set your environment variables:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include"
```

- use pip to install cryptography

  - `pip install cryptography`

After this I had a functional python with cryptography installed and I was then able to install fabric (via `pip install fabric==1.14.1` since 1.14.1 is the version I need for this old project, use what you need)

**Edit:**
Thanks to @CharlesDuffy for all of his help and as he correctly mentions in the comments bellow, you could (and probably should) install all of the dependencies and cryptography from nix instead of using a combination of brew and nix.  I had brew and the dependancies installed before I had Nix installed so I haven't tested it out, but it *should* work.

Comment: You can have Nix do the job of installing libtiff, openssl, the cryptography package, etc. as well -- I don't install Homebrew at all, personally. (The same repository of build steps used to populate the set of buildable packages on MacOS is also used for NixOS, a full-featured Linux distro -- generally speaking, everything one might want is there).

Comment: Yeah, I would probably recommend anyone else who needs to do this do that, but I had already installed homebrew, libiff, openssl, etc. before I had even heard of Nix so I really had done that weeks ago and then just installed Nix and python2 today and since I already had libiff, openssl, etc. installed I just tried it with them and it worked so I said, "good enough"