# Issues installing python using pyenv on macOS M1

Tags: python, zsh, macos-big-sur, pyenv

I was trying to prepare multi-version python development environment using pyenv. I've succesfully installed the pyenv. I installed the pyenv through homebrew (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-macos). But when I was trying to install a python version, I've encountered an error:

```
➜  live_xr_cms_api git:(dev) ✗ pyenv install 3.9.6
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/b_/4pdsw1_15bx8l23n5wbblflc0000gn/T/python-build.20210712183213.13974
Results logged to /var/folders/b_/4pdsw1_15bx8l23n5wbblflc0000gn/T/python-build.20210712183213.13974.log

Last 10 log lines:
                        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
        fi
Looking in links: /var/folders/b_/4pdsw1_15bx8l23n5wbblflc0000gn/T/tmp85zin3_g
Processing /private/var/folders/b_/4pdsw1_15bx8l23n5wbblflc0000gn/T/tmp85zin3_g/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /private/var/folders/b_/4pdsw1_15bx8l23n5wbblflc0000gn/T/tmp85zin3_g/pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/Users/anzhari/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.
Successfully installed pip-21.1.3 setuptools-56.0.0
```

Comment: Use Nix instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65653464/14122

Comment: That said, if you're really attached to pyenv, https://squademy.medium.com/install-python-on-macos-11-m1-apple-silicon-using-pyenv-12e0729427a9 is suggested by another answer on that question. Personally, though, I can only help with the Nix approach.

Comment: I've given on trying to make pyenv work. Ended up using conda miniforge instead.

Comment: Consider deleting the question, if you're no longer pursuing an answer

Answer (score 7):

Execute the command from the Rosetta Terminal

> pyenv install [version]

Comment: Omg, so easy. I thought previously installed rosetta homebrew is enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035003/installing-cryptography-on-an-apple-silicon-m1-mac/66422219?noredirect=1#comment118654852_66422219. But it seems pyenv triggers "outside" xcode sdk. Thanks!