# Cannot download Python 3.6 with miniforge (conda-forge)

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, apple-m1, conda-forge

I'm somewhat new to this. I recently set up my M1 Mac with miniforge to run the accelerated version of tensor flow (via apples accelerator). Because of this, all my conda environments run in python 3.8+. When I try to install a lower 3.6 version for an environment, I get these messages:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.6
```

Or this:

```
% conda search python 
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                         3.8.5 h05baefb_8_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h12cc5a1_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.6 h3098bc4_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.8 h12cc5a1_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 h69cb8a9_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 hab31e5c_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.10 hf9733c0_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.11 h35b60ff_4_cpython  pkgs/main           
python                        3.8.11      hbdb9e5c_5  pkgs/main           
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hab31e5c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.8.12 hd949e87_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h4b4120c_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hd001b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 hf1b0709_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                      3.9.1rc1 h4b4120c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 h4b4120c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hcbd9b3a_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.2 hcbd9b3a_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.4 h5b20da3_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.5 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6 h54d631c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6      hc70090a_5  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 h54d631c_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hc0da0df_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7      hc70090a_1  pkgs/main           
python                        3.10.0 h43b31ca_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0 h70c1b39_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.10.0      hbdb9e5c_1  pkgs/main
```

Are lower python packages not available through conda-forge? How can I install a lower version without going through the hassle of reinstalling something like Miniconda again, the installation of miniforge to run adaptively with the M1 chip was hard enough as is...

I just need a virtual environment that runs python 3.6 that I can somehow install via conda-forge. Or if that doesn't work, could I install some sort of virtual machine to not interfere with my current setup? What is the best thing I can do here?

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.6 [is not available on M1](https://bugs.python.org/msg382939), unfortunately: **"There are no plans to backport support to 3.7 and 3.6 which are in the security-fix-only phase of their release cycles."**

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980989/14458327), someone suggests to use Nix, you can take a look.

I also found some newer solution with [using miniconda](https://blog.balasundar.com/install-older-versions-of-python-using-miniconda-on-mac-m1), maybe you can try with that.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see there was another question about it. Will try that !